# Wordpress Query / Loop duplicating same content 24 times

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, loops

I'm having a small query issue that maybe you can help me with. I am trying to get all comments from a post that has a particular comment meta. This is what I have so far:

```
$comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments INNER JOIN wp_commentmeta WHERE comment_post_ID = '256' AND comment_approved = '1' AND meta_key = 'bestcomment' AND meta_value = 'yes' ");  ?>
<ul id="bestcomment">
<h2>Best Comment</h2>
<?php
if ( $comments ) : foreach ( (array) $comments as $comment) :
echo  '<li class="recentcomments">' . sprintf(__('%1$s on %2$s'), get_comment_author_link(), '<a href="'. get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID) . '">' . get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID) . '</a>') . '</li>';
endforeach; endif;?></ul>
```

This post should only have one comment. Unfortunately, the query is displaying the same result 24 times. So there has to be something wrong with the loop. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks to JW, I fixed the issue:

<?php $comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments INNER JOIN $wpdb->commentmeta ON($wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id) WHERE comment_post_ID = '256' AND comment_approved = '1' AND meta_key = 'bestcomment' AND meta_value = 'yes' ");  ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the loop. The problem is that your query produces `cartesian product` (*CROSS JOIN*) because you didn't specify the column on which the two tables should be link.

The fastest answer I can give is to define the linking columns on the `ON` clause,

```
$comments = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->comments a
      INNER JOIN wp_commentmeta b
         ON a.ColumnName = b.Columnname           <== define here
WHERE comment_post_ID = '256' AND 
      comment_approved = '1' AND 
      meta_key = 'bestcomment' AND 
       meta_value = 'yes' ");
```

just change `ColumnName` into the real name of the column in your table.

To learn more about `JOIN`, please take a look at the article below,

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: You were completely right! Thanks. I changed it and now it is displaying correctly.

Comment: As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values. [see How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)